# SSH connection problem (timeout) from outside to ppp0 interface (4G modem) on Raspberry Pi

Tags: linux, ssh, modem, 3g

I am having difficulty establishing SSH connection from outside to Raspberry Pi that has USB 4G modem as interface. I get timeout when trying to connect with ssh:

```
ssh -l pi ccc.ccc.ccc.ccc -p 22
ssh_exchange_identification: read: Operation timed out
```

Interface is obviously ppp0 and has correct IP address that can be pinged from outside. This is the ifconfig listing (ip address obfuscated)

```
ppp0: flags=4305<UP,POINTOPOINT,RUNNING,NOARP,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
    inet ccc.ccc.ccc.ccc  netmask 255.255.255.255  destination 10.64.64.64
    ppp  txqueuelen 3  (Point-to-Point Protocol)
    RX packets 401  bytes 377702 (368.8 KiB)
    RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
    TX packets 336  bytes 27694 (27.0 KiB)
    TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

ping from an other machine works OK, ssh does not and gets timeout. Monitoring the interface with tcpdumps shows some life when connected with ssh client

```
sudo tcpdump -i ppp0 port 22 
tcpdump: verbose output suppressed, use -v or -vv for full protocol decode
listening on ppp0, link-type LINUX_SLL (Linux cooked), capture size 262144 bytes
09:18:26.764806 IP yyy.yyy.yyy.yyy.53681 > ccc.ccc.ccc.ccc.ssh: Flags [S], seq 2675400197, win 65535, options [mss 1386,nop,wscale 5,nop,nop,TS val 672664602 ecr 0,sackOK,eol], length 0
```

after that there is no life, no logs in /var/log/auth or messages, nothing. sshd log level is set to DEBUG3

This is the SSHD conf file:

```
Port 22 
Port 7654
AddressFamily any
ListenAddress 0.0.0.0
#ListenAddress ::


# Ciphers and keying
#RekeyLimit default none

# Logging
SyslogFacility AUTH
LogLevel DEBUG3
```

I tried to add some obscure port 7654 in case 22 was blocked by ISP or something

I tried to add specific firewall rules even though general policy is set to ACCEPT:

```
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT) 
target     prot opt source               destination         
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:ssh ctstate NEW,ESTABLISHED
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:7654 ctstate NEW,ESTABLISHED

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp spt:ssh ctstate ESTABLISHED
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp spt:7654 ctstate ESTABLISHED
```

route table looks like this:

```
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         10.64.64.64     0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 ppp0
10.64.64.64     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.255 UH    0      0        0 ppp0
bbb.bbb.bbb.0    0.0.0.0         255.255.252.0   U     202    0        0 eth0
```

where that bbb thing is local ethernet network

No luck, and I still get timeout when trying to connect. SSH from localhost to that IP address works ok.

Any ideas where this is going wrong and how to fix it? It puzzles me that I get at least ICMP messages to the interface and internally SSH also works. Even externally there is some life in that interface when connecting from outside with ssh, but it still doesn't work.

Comment: Possibly related https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/8342/85990

Answer (score 0):

You should specify one obscure port, **restart SSH daemon**, then try again.

---

Further, you have your firewall open completely... no comment on this, but you don't need to add any ACCEPT rules then.

---

I personally recommend using a **custom port above 50000**. Read the [Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_TCP_and_UDP_port_numbers) in order not to make this mistake twice.

---

In any case, I recommend you to look at [my answer on Security SE](https://security.stackexchange.com/q/154076/82570) to harden your security.

Comment: I agree about the firewall. It was just to check if something weird were wrong there. You are how ever wrong about the sshd not being able to listen more than one port, it totally can. I can ssh on either one of those ports without an issue now.

Answer (score 0):

Ok so the problem was with routing. As I quit trials and plugged ethernet cable from Raspberry it started working. Good thing I did try to take one last login attempt. 
I don't know if the problem was on Raspberry end or with the machine I used for testing. Testing machine was plugged with ethernet to the same Raspberry and I suppose the reply packets were sent via ethernet rather than ppp connection which would obviously result them being rejected at testing machine (if they ever arrived).